# C Sysmalloc assertion failure

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, assertion

I am getting the below sysmalloc error in running a C program.

```
malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *)
&((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd))))
&& old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)
((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))
+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)))
&& ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
```

The program works fine when using an int array

```
int(*M)[cnt] = malloc(sizeof(int[cnt][cnt]));
```

but is showing the above error for signed long int. There is no other change made in the program.

```
signed long int(*M)[cnt] = malloc(sizeof(signed long int[cnt][cnt]));
```

What could be the reason? This worked perfectly when using an int array. Hence there shouldn't be a problem with memory management as given here 
[C Malloc assertion failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987207/why-do-i-get-a-c-malloc-assertion-failure)

Thanks

Comment: What is `cnt`? Are you on a 32 or 64 bit system? What is `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(long)` on your system?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get a C malloc assertion failure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987207/why-do-i-get-a-c-malloc-assertion-failure)

Comment: @mch: cnt is an integer variable storing some value. I am on 64 bit system. `sizeof(int)` is 4 and `sizeof(long)` is 8.

Comment: What the typical size of `cnt`?

Comment: @meaning-matters: In the particular case that I am working on, it is somewhere around 30

Comment: have you tried `void *tmp = malloc(cnt * cnt * sizeof(long));`? Your syntax is a little bit uncommon.

Comment: @mch: I did know that, but the above used one is the best suitable method in my case.

Answer (score 1):

This assertion expression looks like a sanity check to see if the allocation internal data structures are still intact.

This internal data is often placed before and/or after the allocated blocks.  If something is wrong, it means that your code that executed before this `malloc()` has been writing outside the bounds of an earlier allocated block.

EDIT: Doing a google search for `Assertion (old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *)
&((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) -` directly led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2987207/1971013).  Didn't you do a google search?

Comment: yup. I searched and checked that answer. That didn't help my problem. If it was the case mentioned in the other answer it shouldn't work for the int array as well.

Comment: Not a good conclusion because issues like this can appear and disappear depending on where allocated blocks are placed, or how far they stretch. The programming mistake can be in a totally different and seemingly unrelated place, but the fact is that your code is writing where it's not supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

My own experience, which might help: This is definitely a failure because of some dynamically allocated memory which is used incorrectly (for example, out of bound assignment). The tricky thing is that the failure might not occur in exactly the line where the out of bounds is happening.

For example, this was my code:

```
int func(const int n) {
    int *a = new int[n]; // * sizeof(int)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        a[i] = 1;

    // This line causes the sysmalloc assertion failure
    vector<int> tv(10);
}
```

Now the failure happens when memory is allocated for `tv`, but the actual problem is that I forgot the `* sizeof(int)` while allocating memory and hence in the loop, wrote in non allocated memory addresses.